# Simple CPU design in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I am trying to use a wire variable which will hold the output of some other module and provide it as an input to the another module. While trying to change its value initially from the test bench, it's showing an error as described below. Here ***tb.v*** is the name of the test bench file.

> tb.v:39: error: a is not a valid l-value in TB.
>    tb.v:4: error: a is declared here as wire. 1 error(s) during elaboration.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Use your testbench to control when the module2 input is driven by the module1 output or the testbench.

```
reg tb_in, tb_drive;
wire out1;
wire in2 = (tb_drive) ? tb_in : out1;
mod1 mod1 (out1);
mod2 mod2 (in2);
```